# Highcharts data grouping method for objects

Tags: highcharts

I've been working with some of the data grouping functionality of the HighStock library and have been having trouble aggregating complex data point objects.

Data grouping works fantastic for a single y value, but as far as I can tell there isn't a method for specifying how grouping should be achieved for a data point object. Just wondering if there's anyone out there who has encountered a similar problem and what my options are in approaching this.

The data points that I'm trying to group have this structure:

```
datapoint : {
    x: time,
    y: value(percentage),
    average: averageLengthOfObjects,
    converted: <int>,
    total: <int>,
    attributes: <list data>
}
```

It would be okay to ignore all of the supplemental data point information as long as it is still accessible at the most granular level for display in a tooltip, but data grouping seems to just throw out all of the additional information contained in my data points.  Ideally I'd like to supply my own implementation of grouping these objects for a particular range, but I know it may not be possible.

At any rate, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is default behaviour, that only y values is "pushed" into grouped point, because in case when you have string parameters, which should be chosen from group? So we decided to skip grouping other parameters.

Obviously you have possibility to prepare your own grouping function, http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.approximation

Comment: Thanks Sebastian!  Not sure how I missed the approximation configuration parameter, but this is exactly what I was looking for.